# How to show the zip code boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geocoding

I want to know how to show the ZIP code boundaries in QGIS. For example when I type the zip code the screen need to be zoomed to that zip code area with boundaries, just like its working in google maps.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

QGIS is GIS software, you don't use it the same way as google maps.
You need to use SQL language to perform queries on your data.
Here is an example of a simple query to zoom on a feature (sorry my QGIS is in french, but you'll find the same buttons on yours):

- **1.** First use the advanced filter at the bottom of your attribute table (or use directly the select tool, depends on your needs)
- **2.** Once you've selected the feature you want, click on the little button to zoom on your feature

[image: Query example]

Comment: Yes, but in this case I must to have a polygone shapefile with zip code boundaries. Do you have any idea how to download this shapefile?

Comment: You can try to go here for US data : https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html . If you work on an other country look for the national mapping agency (Ordnance Survey in the UK...)

Comment: I need it for India...

Comment: Does anybody have a zip code boundary shapefile of India or know where I can get it??